# Bootstrap navbar doesnt toggle and brand moves with it

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Hi I try to toggle the menu with bootstrap but if i press the button it just toggle for 0.35s and then it disappear or better to say it is not shown.
Also if its toggling the navbar-brand button is toggle with the rest of menupoint

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
   <button class="btn Menu-button navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menupoint">Menu</button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menupoint">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-3">
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="/" class="nav-link">Home</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="/gallery" class="nav-link">artist</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="/buySell" class="nav-link">buy</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="/contact" class="nav-link">contact</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <button class="btn Menu-button navbar-brand">branding</button>
  </nav>
```

I tried to change the positions of the buttons and i also tested in codepen, but there it doesnt worked anyway. i hope i didn't make a stupid mistake.
I am using bootstrap 4 and I'm quiet new

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
<button class="btn Menu-button navbar-brand">branding</button>
        <button class="btn Menu-button navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menupoint">Menu</button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menupoint">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-3">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="/" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="/gallery" class="nav-link">artist</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="/buySell" class="nav-link">buy</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="/contact" class="nav-link">contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </nav>
```

I don't know what the class **Menu-button** is doing here, but you said that when you press the button it just toggle for 0.35s and then it disappears, maybe you have put some kind of animation by using this class or performing some kind of jquery action. Better to check this.
And one more thing if you are using Bootstrap, then use it in its way. I mean if you want a navbar with a toggle effect then you can make it like this.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>    
    </ul>
  </div>  
</nav>
```

Or you can follow this link:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_navbar.asp